# Krajee Bootstrap File Input plugin pdf preview doesn't work in chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this plugin and can't figure out why my chrome doesn't show preview of pdf when file is selected...on their website it shows perfectly fine

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-icons-demo#custom-preview-icons-3

but on my local file it works with firefox but not with chrome, i get only a blank preview

## like this

[image]

## And it should be like this:

[image]

I have uploaded the main gist from github and added my file inside /examples/myfile.html

[MY EDITED EXAMPLE](http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/X93zCO5D/file.html)

Please if someone could help me i don't get it what am i doing wrong? Maybe there are some other dependencies that I'm not loading in html file?? Or something should be loaded before one another?

Just run the /examples/myfile.html in chrome and select any .pdf and you will see what am i talking about.

## update

this is my html file inside that zip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- release v4.3.6, copyright 2014 - 2016 Kartik Visweswaran -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>myfile</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container kv-main">
            <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Bootstrap File Input Example</h1>
            </div>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="upload" class="file" type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="1">
                <br>
            </form>


            
    </body>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    
    $("#upload").fileinput({

        // 

    });

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out...

It doesn't work out of the box just like that....it must be pulled from the real server...like from apache or nginx or xampp or mamp